# Unexpected SQL Results - Need advice

Tags: sql, subquery

The top query is just showing the results I am expecting before I join another table to perform some calculations in Crystal Reports.

```
select 
    DriveID, FromDateTime, accountid, LocationID, StatusID 
from 
    DriveMaster 
where 
    AccountID = '3813' 
order by 
    FromDateTime desc;
```

Results:

[Query Results](http://i62.tinypic.com/j8p72h.png)

This second query is where I apply a couple of filters (specifying `accountid, locationid, statusid`, and which occur before a specific date).

```
select 
    dm.driveid, dm.fromdatetime, dm.accountid, dpact.ProcedureProjection,
    dpact.ProceduresPerformed, dpact.ProductProjection, dpact.ProductsCollected,
    dm.locationid
from 
    rpt_drivemaster dm
inner join 
    driveprojectionandcollectedtotals dpact on dm.driveid = dpact.driveid
where 
    dm.statusid = 2
    and dm.accountid = '3813'
    and dm.locationid = '4018'
    and dm.fromdatetime < '20140602'
    and dm.fromdatetime in (select top 3 dm2.fromdatetime 
                            from rpt_drivemaster dm2
                            where dm2.accountid = '3813' 
                              and dm2.statusid = 2 
                            order by dm2.fromdatetime desc);
```

The only results I am getting however are:

[Query Results 2](http://i58.tinypic.com/2hnqnog.png)

Based on the earlier query, I was expecting results for DriveIDs of:

```
 1. 314933
 2. 205250
 3. 184779
```

Any suggestions on what I am missing here?

Comment: As far as I can (quickly) see, either one of the 3 rows from the subquery doesn't have locationid 4018, or there exists no row in `driveprojectionandcollectedtotals` with driveid 184779...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your subquery that is passed in the `IN` – it is returning three rows with `DriverID` `548002`,`314933` and `205250`. The first row has `LocationID = 31036` so it doesn't go in the result set because in your main query there is a condition `dm.locationid='4018'`.You should pass this condition in the subquery too, to get the desired result :

```
select top 3 dm2.fromdatetime 
from rpt_drivemaster dm2
where dm2.accountid='3813' 
  and dm2.statusid=2
  and dm2.LocationID = '4018' 
order by dm2.fromdatetime desc
```